# Rails 4: Can't create a session for a user through login, although the session is created when I create a new user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication

I'm creating a very basic log in session following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hw6WtWJwRtU

Following the tutor exactly what he does I encountered many errors probably because he uses an older Rails version. So now the problem is that when I try to login the system doesn't actually log me in while after creating a user the session is created as well and everything works fine.
Here's my application layout that shows you if the user is logged in

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Fitit</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
  <% if current_user %>
  <p>
    Logges in as <%= current_user.username %>
    <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path %>
  </p>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Sign Up", signup_path %>
    <%#= link_to "Set Profile", profile_path %>
    <%= link_to "Log In", login_path %>
  <% end %>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Then there's a view to create a new session(mind a had many problems with this part of code: <%#= form_tag session_path do %> -  the on tutor used and it results in an error and asks for an :id, which I tried to pass there almost anything.

```
<h1>Log In</h1>

<%#= form_tag session_path do %>
<%= form_tag({controller: "sessions", action: "create"}, method: "get") do %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :username %><br/>
    <%= text_field_tag :username, params[:username] %><br/>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :password %><br/>
    <%= password_field_tag :password %><br/>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag "Log In" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Then here's my Sessions controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create

    user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
    respond_to do |format|
      if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        format.html { redirect_to :index, notice: 'Logged In successfully' }
        format.json { render :index, status: :created, location: @session }
      else
        flash.now.alert = "Email or password is invalid"
        render "new"
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Logged Out successfully' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end

  end

end
```

Where I think the problem lies. And just to compare a CREATE method from User controller which does actually create a session.

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :sessions
  resources :foods

  resources :users do
    resources :entries
  end

  post "log_in" => "sessions#new", :as => "log_in"
  get "logout" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "logout"
  get "login" => "sessions#new", :as => "login"
  get "signup" => "users#new", :as => "signup"

  root :to => 'users#new'

  get "app/views/users/profile.html.erb", to: "users#profile", as: "profile"
end
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here? I'm trying to tackle this problem for the second day already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On form_tag use POST (default one) method instead of GET.

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "sessions", action: "create"}) do %>
```

Because on your router file, the line:

resources :sessions

will generate something like that:

> sessions POST /sessions(.:format)    sessions#create
>
> # ...